# If $ m $ is the minimal polynomial of $ T $, then is it true that $ m(T^k) = 0 $ for every $ k \in \mathbb{N} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

I came up with a statement which I think is false, but not sure what example to give for the falsification:
Let $ T: V \to V $ be a linear operator.
If $ m $ is the minimal polynomial of $ T $, then is it true that $ m(T^k) = 0 $ for every $ k \in \mathbb{N} $?

I thought I'd give an example of some matrix $ A $, calculate its characteristic polynomial $ \Delta_A(x) $ and by Cayley-Hamilton theorem I know that $ \Delta_A(A) = 0  $, so I'd just find a matrix $ A $ s.t. $ \Delta_A(A^k) \neq 0 $ for some $ k$.

Comment: Can you prove it for $1\times 1$ matrices?

Comment: I think that would be helpful but I'm not sure if it would be one of those special cases for which the statement fails ( like some statements do for fields of characteristic 2 ) but stays true for every other square matrix of size larger than $ 1 $. ( Maybe a different question would be if there exists a size of a square matrix for which the statement would be true for all matrices of that size )

Comment: Multiples of the identity behave a lot like numbers (i.e., $1\times 1$ matrices).

Comment: You're right, haven't thought about identity matrices in that way. I still can't fully think of an example, I need another hint. If the theorem's indeed true, proof by induction would be the way to go here.

Comment: Have you thought about the $1\times 1$ problem seriously?

Comment: Write down an actual matrix. Literally any matrix. (Ok, well maybe not a matrix for which $T^2 = T$.) And then compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}\implies A^2=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&4\end{pmatrix}$$

$$p_A(t)=(t-1)^2(t-2)\,,\;\;m_A(t)=(t-1)(t-2)\;\text{(because A is diagonal...)}$$

But

$$m_A(A^2)=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&3\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\0&-1&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&6\end{pmatrix}\neq\overline 0$$

The claim is false, thus.

Comment: Great counterexample. BTW I think there is a missing equals sign at the end :)!

Comment: @AsukaLangleySohryu Good catch. Thankx.

Comment: Or.....$A=[2]$.

Comment: @JamieRadcliffe The case of square matrices of order one was already covered in the comments.

Comment: @DonAntonio Right. My point there was that **everything** is a counterexample pretty much. In particular any diagonal matrix with any diagonal entry that isn't $0$ or a root of unity.